# Entity reference link module

Tags: navigation, entities

I am using entity reference field in a content type with select list widget allows you to add the title of a node in the content type, however the title dose not work as a link to the node.
I would like to now how can i make the title work as a link to the node?

dose Entity Reference link module fits this purpose??
if yes how it works?
if no is there any way to do this??

Comment: title always work as a link to that particular content..

Comment: No need to installed other module. Title always hold the link..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *Manage Display* of the content type that contains *field reference* field, Select *Rendered Entity* of *Format* of the field. I mean this

[image]

and using that widget you can select a custom *Display mode* and by that display mode you can choose what fields of the referenced content must be displayed (title or any other field).

Answer (score 0):

Go to  `Content types » [your_content_type] » Manage display`
and select FORMAT as `Link label to the referenced entity` for your referenced field.